# CurieBLE: /ble_service/ble_protocol.h: no such file or directory

Tags: c++, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I rewrote a program from [here](https://www.hackster.io/gov/imu-to-you-ae53e1#comments) and combined it with the **Adafruit BNO055** program so to read the calibration data on an **Android** app I made on MITs App Inventor.

I'm getting the following error:

```
C:\Program Files
(x86)\Arduino\libraries\CurieBLE\src/BLECommon.h:26:54: fatal error:
../src/services/ble_service/ble_protocol.h: No such file or directory
```

Looking through the folders (both on my PC and github) I can find the `BLECommon`, but there is no `'ble_service'`...though there is a `'BLEService'`. I also can't find a `'ble_protocol.h'` anywhere.

Can anyone help me understand what I may be doing wrong, and how I can remedy this error?

Comment: Did you follow these [installation instructions](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Arduino101) for the **Intel Curie Board** first?

Comment: I just realized the problem is probably that I'm not using a Curie board (silly, I know). I'm using an Arduino Uno, with the intentions of using the code on an Adafruid Feather board later. 

Any suggestions on easy to use code for using SPI BLE? I need something that sends the code in a simple float array, so I know how to expect the data coming into the Android app (the MIT App Inventor is fairly simple).

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do something similar - use a PlatformIO compiler as part of my CI process in Gitlab. I received a similar error when compiling so I went looking for the missing files and found them here (note, I'm using linux so adjust accordingly for Windows):

```
/.arduino15/packages/Intel/hardware/arc32/2.0.2/system/libarc32_arduino101/framework/src/services/ble_service
```

I moved the ble_service folder to the CurieBLE library folder (within the project folder) so now my project folder structure is:

```
|--lib
|  |--CurieBLE
|  |  |--src
|  |  |  |--bluetooth
|  |  |  |  |[contents of the bluetooth folder from .arduino15/packages/Intel/hardware/arc32/2.0.2/system/libarc32_arduino101/drivers]
|  |  |  |--services
|  |  |  |  |--ble_service
|  |  |  |  |  |[contents of the ble_service folder from above path]
|  |  |  |[rest of the CurieBLE folder contents]
|--src
|  |- main.cpp
|- platformio.ini
```

I'm still working through other errors to get PlatformIO to work but this at least fixed the missing libraries/files.